# Oracle apex cascading numeric values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, numeric, cascade

I have the following coefficient table for exams.

```
val_disp | val_ret
   %0    |    0
  %10    |   0.1
  %20    |   0.2
  %30    |   0.3
  %40    |   0.4
  %50    |   0.5
  %60    |   0.6
  %70    |   0.7
  %80    |   0.8
  %90    |   0.9
 %100    |    1
```

And I listing these values as lov in select lists like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/89jAo.jpg

Is it possible to cascade these values to sum up %100? For ex... if I choose %30 for midterm and %40 for final, max available value for assignment can be cascaded to %30 by summing up 2 item value?

And how can I use val_ret of selected list item in sql query?

Or am I in a realy realy wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "Cascading LOV parent item(s)" property to previous LOVs.

In a LOV query, reference previously set values.

For example:

**LOV_1**:

```
select '%' || 10 * (level - 1) val_disp,
       (level - 1) / 10 val_ret
from dual
connect by level <= 11;
```

**LOV_2**: cascading LOV is LOV_1

```
select '%' || 10 * (level - 1) val_disp,
       (level - 1) / 10 val_ret
from dual
connect by level <= (1 - :LOV_1) * 10 + 1;
```

**LOV_3**: cascading LOVs are LOV_1 and LOV_2

```
select '%' || 10 * (level - 1) val_disp,
       (level - 1) / 10 val_ret
from dual
connect by level <= (1 - (:LOV_1 + :LOV_2)) * 10 + 1;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks @Littlefoot